# Calculating the boundary of a specific subset of real numbers

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, real-numbers

We construct a sequence of open sets $J_i$as follows. Let $J_0$ be the set $\cup_{n\in \mathbb Z} (2n,2n+1)$. Having constructed $J_0,J_1,...,J_{m-1}$ let $J_m$ be the union of the open middle thirds of the segments constituting $\mathbb R - \cup_{i=0}^{m-1} J_i$. ( I am not sure if the following is an algebraic formulation although as far as I remember I obtained it right: Consider the subsets {$J_m| m=0,1,2,...$} of $\mathbb R$ defined by $$J_m:= \bigcup_{s=0}^{m-1} \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb Z} \left(\frac{3^m(2n+1)+2\times 3^{s}+1}{3^m},\frac{3^m(2n+1)+2\times 3^{s}+2}{3^m}\right),$$ where by definition $2\times 3^0:=0$. If this algebraic formulation is either wrong or right but not useful, dismiss it.)

*1*)  Is it true that the boundary of the union of ***any*** infinite subcollection of {$J_m$} equals the same set (maybe the set of all endpoints of the intervals constituting $J_m$’s)?

*2*)  If not, according to my book from which this question has arisen why the boundary of $\cup_k J_{3k}$, the boundary of $\cup_k J_{3k+1}$, and the boundary of $\cup_k J_{3k+2}$ are the same?

Comment: Have you tried writing out explicitly what $J_m$ is for $m$ up to  $3$ and $n=0,1$?  That may help in seeing what the definition means.

Comment: I’ll clarify the definition now

Comment: I think the definition is fine, but to answer the questions you need to understand what the sets look like.  The $n$ term just makes everything repeat, so what happens in $(0,1)$ happens again in $(1,2)$ and so on.  It is not very important.

Comment: @RossMillikan I illustrated my question.

Comment: @RossMillikan I think even there’s no need for that algebraic formulation, but maybe the algebraic formulation will help that’s why I obtained it

Comment: I was thinking that if you restrict to $n=0$ you should note that $J_2=(\frac 19,\frac 29)\cup (\frac 79,\frac 89)$ and so on

Comment: The two definitions are inconsistent. 

Consider the greatest point in $J_m$ in the two definitions. In the second, this will be $-\frac{1}{3^m}$ (as we continually add the middle third of the closest to the origin segment), however we have:
$-1 + \frac{2 \cdot 3^s + 2}{3^m} \leq \frac{2 \cdot 3^{m-1} + 2}{3^m}-1 = \frac{-1 \cdot 3^{m-1} + 2}{3^m} \leq$
$-\frac 1 3 + \frac 2{9} = -\frac 1 9,$ which is the greatest point in our algebraic formulation.

Comment: @ArtimisFowl I didn’t get you, neither set has a maximum since they are not bounded above

Comment: Sorry, greatest in the interval (-1,0). I pulled the inequalities from an answer in progress where things were better written out.

Comment: I see you've accepted my answer.  Don't forget you can also award the bounty... :)

Comment: Thanks, I thought the reward would be automatically given @Yly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At every step, $\mathbb{R}-\cup_{i=0}^{m} J_i$ consists of a bunch of disjoint intervals of length $3^{-m}$.  This is true for $m=0$ by construction, and inductively at each stage the middle third of each interval in $\mathbb{R}-\cup_{i=0}^{m} J_i$ becomes part of $J_{m+1}$, leaving two intervals with a third the length.

Every boundary point of $J_l$ is a boundary point of $\mathbb{R}-\cup_{i=0}^{m} J_i$ as long as $l\leq m$, and every boundary point of $\mathbb{R}-\cup_{i=0}^{m} J_i$ is within a distance $3^{-m}$ of some boundary point of $J_{m+1}$.  Hence, given any infinite collection of $\{J_i\}$, we can construct a sequence of boundary points $\{x_i\in J_i\}$ from them which converges to any boundary point of $J_l$.

Since the $J_i$ are open and disjoint, their boundary points are not contained in any other $J_i$'s.  From this it follows that the boundary of the union of a collection $\{J_i\}$ contains the union of their boundaries.  For any boundary point $x$ of some $J_l$ is not in $\cup \{J_i\}$, but it is arbitrarily close to points thereof, hence it is in the boundary of $\cup \{J_i\}$.

Hence, given any infinite collection $\{J_i\}$, we can find a sequence in the boundary of their union converging to any boundary point of any $J_l$.  Since the boundary is closed, this means that any boundary point of $J_l$ is in the boundary of the union of $\{J_i\}$.  This proves your point $1$.